# how to raw bubble like bubble shooter game in libgdx game

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, jstilemap

i would like to make Bubble shooter game. but issue is that how i draw bubble 10 row and 10 column wise bubble with different color in libgdx...is this bubble draw through tilemap or any other way.

Comment: Seems like this question has no more to do with box2d than it has to do with computers. Perhaps drop the box2d tag?

Answer (score 0):

If your row is fixed then simply you can draw on game screen in 2D array and add pading in row depending upon even or odd row number. But if your row changes from then 10 means increase then you can use ArrayList.

Bubble Images can be taken from json file if you have predefined bubble color otherwise you can generate random bubble.

Comment: how to destroy the body. i would store 10 different body in an array ex: int GameMatrix[]= {1,2,2,2,5,8,2,1,1,1 } ;
I like to search number 2 then there are 4times of a number so I like to destroy four bodies destroy at the same time. 
there is remain six bodies only in box2d libgdx?

Comment: then what's the problem, just destroy four box2d body.

Comment: it doesn't destroy four bodies from the array which is a match with2

Comment: First of All if you're making bubble shooter game then box2d is not good solution in my recommendation, try to implement bubble motion by yourself and at the end when you can't ignore physics simulation then use box2d like if bubble fall after deattatchment and need to make some tuple on ground then use there.